# How to avoid Rails caching from causing child objects to appear to not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm working on an order application, which is accepting orders from the CC Processing vendor, and passing them off to a fulfillment application.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, class_name: 'Product'
  def payload
    @builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      ...
      self.items.each do |o|
        ...
      end
    end
    @builder.to_xml
  end
  ...
end
```

When an order comes in, it creates all of the needed records, and then tries to pass of the payload to the fulfillment application

```
def generate_order
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    # create order
    ...
    External.send_order(self) # Web Call to Customer Support system <= this is were caching is happening
    Product.create!(...) #create the actual product items
    p "Payload #{self.payload}"
  rescue StandardError => e
    ...
  end
end
```

Because we are passing the order itself to Customer Support system, before we've actually processed the items, Rails is caching the order without any items.  So when we try to view the payload, the items aren't present.

I can move the callout to the customer support system until after we process the items and work around it, but..

How can we ensure that we are working from a current/non-cached version of the order?

Comment: I do not think this has anything to do with caching. Is this line `p "Payload #{self.payload}"` actually inside the transaction block? The issue may be that the transaction has not been committed yet, which means the records you are trying to retrieve do not actually exist.  Can you post the logs around calling this method?

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for your response.  It is within the transaction block, but moving the External.send_order(self) to after the Product.create!() allows for for "Payload #{self.payload}" to see the items that were created.

Comment: I have no idea what `External::send_order` does since this code is not posted but you can [`reload`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/reload) the association in `payload` e.g. `self.items.reload`

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks!  the reload method is what I am looking for.  If you can put it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied From Comment: I have no idea what `External::send_order` does since this code is not posted.

That being said if you have a cached relationship and you wish to update it you can use [`ActiveRecord::Relation#reload`](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord%2FRelation%3Areload) to do so. e.g.

```
self.items.reload.each do |o|
#...
end
```

What this method does is resets the relationship and then loads the records again. This means it will fire a query to recollect all the records for the relationship so be careful where and how you go about using this (would not recommend using it inside a loop or iterator)